Unexpected results from Metal computing
EDIT:
In the comment below, pmdj pointed out 2 bugs in my code.
For clarity, I will not copy all the code and output buffer contents. Instead I modified both and left the originals as comments.
Original question:
I am trying to understand Metal computing, but I get completely unexpected results, even with the most simple code that I can imagine. Here is my setup:
I have the following unit test function:
func test_test() throws {
    let metalImageProcessor = MetalImageProcessor()!
    metalImageProcessor.test()
}

The idea is that after the test completed, I can check the logs in the debugger.
My MetalImageProcessor is the following:
    func test() {
        let device = MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice()!
        let commandQueue = device.makeCommandQueue()!
        let library = device.makeDefaultLibrary()!
        let testFunction = library.makeFunction(name: "testFunction")!
        let pipelineState = try! device.makeComputePipelineState(function: testFunction)
        let commandBuffer = commandQueue.makeCommandBuffer()!
        let commandEncoder = commandBuffer.makeComputeCommandEncoder()!
    
        let threadExecutionWidth  = makeTexturePipelineState.threadExecutionWidth
        let threadExecutionHeight = makeTexturePipelineState.maxTotalThreadsPerThreadgroup / threadExecutionWidth
        let threadsPerThreadgroup = MTLSize(width: threadExecutionWidth, height: threadExecutionHeight, depth: 1) 
        let threadsPerGrid = MTLSize(width: threadExecutionWidth, height: threadExecutionHeight, depth: 1)
        
        let outputBufferSize = threadsPerGrid.width * threadsPerGrid.height * MemoryLayout<Float>.size * 10 // shader writes 10 floats per thread  
// WAS: let outputBufferSize = threadsPerGrid.width * threadsPerGrid.height * MemoryLayout<Float>.size // shader writes 10 floats
        var buffer1 = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: outputBufferSize)
        let outputBuffer1 = device.makeBuffer(bytes: &buffer1, length: outputBufferSize, options: .storageModeShared)
        
        commandEncoder.setComputePipelineState(pipelineState)
        commandEncoder.setBuffer(outputBuffer1, offset: 0, index: 0)
    
        commandEncoder.dispatchThreadgroups(threadsPerGrid, threadsPerThreadgroup: threadsPerThreadgroup)
        commandEncoder.endEncoding()
        commandBuffer.commit()
        commandBuffer.waitUntilCompleted()
        
        debugBufferValues(name: "outputBuffer1", buffer: outputBuffer1!, width: threadExecutionWidth, height: threadExecutionHeight)
    }
    
    func debugBufferValues(name: String, buffer: MTLBuffer, width: Int, height: Int) {
        let debugData = buffer.contents().bindMemory(to: Float.self, capacity: width * height)
        print("\n")
        for i in 0 ..< min(width * height, 8320) {
            print(name, "[\(i)]: \(debugData[i])")
        }
    }

It calls the following shader kernel function:
kernel void testFunction(device float *outputBuffer [[buffer(0)]],
                         uint2 gridSize [[grid_size]],
                         uint2 threadGroupIDinGrid [[threadgroup_position_in_grid]],
                         uint2 threadIDinThreadGroup [[thread_position_in_threadgroup]],
                         uint2 threadGroupSize [[threads_per_threadgroup]],
                         uint2 gid [[thread_position_in_grid]]) {
    uint nrFloatsPerThread = 10; // see below
    // uint testValueIndex = 0; // start value // out commented 
    uint outputBufferIndex = (gridSize.x * gid.y + gid.x) * nrFloatsPerThread; // WAS: uint outputBufferIndex = (gridSize.x * gid.y + gid.x) * nrFloatsPerThread + testValueIndex;

    outputBuffer[outputBufferIndex] = gridSize.x;               outputBufferIndex += 1; // WAS: testValueIndex += 1;
    outputBuffer[outputBufferIndex] = gridSize.y;               outputBufferIndex += 1; // WAS: testValueIndex += 1;
    outputBuffer[outputBufferIndex] = threadGroupIDinGrid.x;    outputBufferIndex += 1; // WAS: testValueIndex += 1;
    outputBuffer[outputBufferIndex] = threadGroupIDinGrid.y;    outputBufferIndex += 1; // WAS: testValueIndex += 1;
    outputBuffer[outputBufferIndex] = threadIDinThreadGroup.x;  outputBufferIndex += 1; // WAS: testValueIndex += 1;
    outputBuffer[outputBufferIndex] = threadIDinThreadGroup.y;  outputBufferIndex += 1; // WAS: testValueIndex += 1;
    outputBuffer[outputBufferIndex] = threadGroupSize.x;        outputBufferIndex += 1; // WAS: testValueIndex += 1;
    outputBuffer[outputBufferIndex] = threadGroupSize.y;        outputBufferIndex += 1; // WAS: testValueIndex += 1;
    outputBuffer[outputBufferIndex] = gid.x;                    outputBufferIndex += 1; // WAS: testValueIndex += 1;
    outputBuffer[outputBufferIndex] = gid.y;                    outputBufferIndex += 1; // WAS: testValueIndex += 1;
}

What I expected:
Since the grid has the same dimensions as the thread group, there is only a single thread group, in my case of size (32,16,1).
Every thread in this group executes the shader function, and writes 10 floats in the output buffer with the following expected values:
outputBuffer1 [0]: 32.0     // gridSize.x
outputBuffer1 [1]: 16.0     // gridSize.y
outputBuffer1 [2]: 0.0      // threadGroupIDinGrid.x
outputBuffer1 [3]: 0.0      // threadGroupIDinGrid.y
outputBuffer1 [4]: 0.0      // threadIDinThreadGroup.x
outputBuffer1 [5]: 0.0      // threadIDinThreadGroup.y
outputBuffer1 [6]: 32.0     // threadGroupSize.x
outputBuffer1 [7]: 16.0     // threadGroupSize.y
outputBuffer1 [8]: 0.0      // gid.x
outputBuffer1 [9]: 0.0      // gid.y
outputBuffer1 [0]: 32.0     // gridSize.x
outputBuffer1 [1]: 16.0     // gridSize.y
outputBuffer1 [2]: 0.0      // threadGroupIDinGrid.x
outputBuffer1 [3]: 0.0      // threadGroupIDinGrid.y
outputBuffer1 [4]: 1.0      // threadIDinThreadGroup.x
outputBuffer1 [5]: 0.0      // threadIDinThreadGroup.y
outputBuffer1 [6]: 32.0     // threadGroupSize.x
outputBuffer1 [7]: 16.0     // threadGroupSize.y
outputBuffer1 [8]: 1.0      // gid.x
outputBuffer1 [9]: 0.0      // gid.y  

and so forth.
What I got:
outputBuffer1 [0]: 0.0 // WAS: 250.0
outputBuffer1 [1]: 0.0
outputBuffer1 [2]: 0.0
outputBuffer1 [3]: 15.0 // WAS: 0.0
outputBuffer1 [4]: 0.0
outputBuffer1 [5]: 12.0 // WAS: 0.0
outputBuffer1 [6]: 32.0 // WAS: 0.0
outputBuffer1 [7]: 16.0 // WAS: 0.0
outputBuffer1 [8]: 0.0
outputBuffer1 [9]: 255.0 // WAS: 0.0
outputBuffer1 [10]: 0.0 // WAS: 250.0
outputBuffer1 [11]: 0.0
outputBuffer1 [12]: 0.0
outputBuffer1 [13]: 15.0 // WAS: 0.0
outputBuffer1 [14]: 1.0 // WAS: 0.0
outputBuffer1 [15]: 12.0 // WAS: 0.0
outputBuffer1 [16]: 32.0 // WAS: 0.0
outputBuffer1 [17]: 16.0 // WAS: 0.0
outputBuffer1 [18]: 1.0 // WAS: 0.0
outputBuffer1 [19]: 255.0 // WAS: 0.0  

and so forth.
Here already the first 10 values in the output buffer are wrong. I neither understand the 250.0 in outputBuffer1 [0], nor the following zeroes.
So something is basically wrong with my code, but I don't find the bug.
Any help is welcome!
EDIT:
What has changed, after the code has been corrected:

gridSize.x and gridSize.y are both 0. I don't understand this.
threadGroupIDinGrid.y is now 15, probably because this value was left by the last thread in the thread group.
gid.y is now 255. Not understood, since there are 32*16 threads in the thread group, so the last index should be 511.


For one, you're incrementing testValueIndex after each outputBuffer write, but indexing by outputBufferIndex. So that's why most of your values are 0. The other thing I spot is that you have shader writes 10 floats but you're only allocating space for 1 float per thread I think? (Sorry, my Swift skills are pretty limited.)

Thanks, pmdj. You are completely right, and these simple bugs embarrass me. After  fixing them, the output looks much better, although I still don't understand all values. I will edit my question ASAP. Could you make your comment an answer? I could accept it then and close the question.

Let's see the updated output and figure out what values are still unexpected.

@ReinhardMänner your buffer1 type should be [Float], not [UInt8].

@HamidYusifli You are right. I copied my code from somewhere without understanding it completely. It should read var buffer1 = [Float](repeating: 0, count: threadsPerGrid.width * threadsPerGrid.height * 10). In this case, I think the output is the same, since I use buffer1 only for writes and it has the correct length.

@ReinhardMänner also, for nonuniform threadgroups you should call: commandEncoder.dispatchThreads, not commandEncoder.dispatchThreadgroups

@HamidYusifli You are right, but this applies only to GPUs that support nonuniform threadgroup sizes. I am using device.supportsFamily(_:) to check if Apple4 family is supported. This is the first family that supports nonuniform threadgroup size, see here. I am developing on a simulator for iPad Pro 13-inch (M4), and this simulator does not support the Apple4 family. That's the reason why I am using dispatchThreadGroups. I hope this is right…
